# Change the text of 'View cart' button - Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I have tried the code suggestions of similar questions on this forum to change the text of View Cart button within functions.php but none worked. I am guessing with the latest WP and WC update, these got depreciated. I am using WP 4.8.8 and WC 3.5.3. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
add_filter( 'gettext', function( $text ) {
if ( 'View cart' === $text ) {
    $text = 'View List';
}
return $text;
} );
```

You need to replace the View Cart with the existing text , and View List with the text you need to update.

[image: woocommerce replace add to cart text]

Answer (score 0):

if you don't find any other solution you could try change it via JS, example:

```
$("a.added_to_cart.wc-forward").text('your new text')
```

UPDATE:

You can create a function to load this snippet then put it in any js file that load with the page.

```
var changeCartName = function (){
  $("a.added_to_cart.wc-forward").text('your new text')
}
changeCartName()
```

Comment: where would i put that snippit?

Comment: yeah, that's why I said if you don't find any other solution